# Base URI while using Furl

Tags: perl

I've checked the documentation https://metacpan.org/pod/Furl
but can't found how can I get sites base URI while using Furl?

With LWP it's easy:

```
my $res = $ua->get($url);
my $base_uri = $res->base;
```

The base function try to get values from this header fields

```
my $base = (
         $self->header('Content-Base'),        # used to be HTTP/1.1
         $self->header('Content-Location'),    # HTTP/1.1
         $self->header('Base'),                # HTTP/1.0
     )[0];
```

But I couldn't do the same with Furl.

Answer (score 3):

First: it seems you want to do an anonymous array at $base, thus, it should be:

`my $base = [
         $res->header('header1'), 
         $res->header('header2'),
         $res->header('header3') 
     ];`

Because the code you had just saved the first header (in your case, Content-Base) and did nothing with the last two, you can check that with *Data::Dumper*.
Maybe that's why it didn't work.

Second: But, after reading through the code of the Furl module, I found out there's no exposed method for getting an url's base, so unless you are also checking in your own code for the `<base>` html tag and the uri you used to request your response (even after redirects), your code might break with some oldish sites. *HTTP::Response* does this checking, and that's what LWP uses.

Citation for hierarchy of base URIs: [HTTP::Response - HTTP style response message](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/HTTP-Message-6.11/lib/HTTP/Response.pm)

Comment: Actually the syntax `$foo = (1, 2, 3)[0]` is fine. It creates a _list_, takes the first element and assigns that to scalar `$foo`. So the _First_ part of your answer is incorrect.

Comment: @simbabque thanks, wow I just realised that it's actually a clever little trick, because problably there's never going to be the three headers together, so if the first and the third one are undefs but the second is defined, it just stores whatever's defined. Clever. Edited away.

Comment: @PatoSáinz:  *"it just stores whatever's defined"* Unfortunately no, it doesn't. Your original draft was correct. `$foo = (undef, 2, 3)[0]` will set `$foo` to `undef`, and the values of the second and third elements of the list are irrelevant. You can simply pick up the first *defined* element of a list by writing `my ($foo) = grep defined, (undef, 2, 3)` But in this case it's probably best to use the *defined-or* operator `//` and write `my $base = $self->header('Content-Base') // $self->header('Content-Location') // $self->header('Base')`

Comment: @simbabque: It seems to me that the only thing wrong with the first part of this post is the supposition that an anonymous array was intended. The paragraph after the code is exactly right

Comment: @Borodin sorry, not undef, you're right. I don't know what value does a $self->header('doesnotexist') takes but try running the OP's script yourself, point it against example.com and try for date, etag and server headers, now change any two of them into gibberish headers and you'll see that $base will be defined by whatever header exists, regardless of whether it came first, second or third. Do tell me if I've explained myself correctly.

Comment: @PatoSáinz: Then the `header` method returns an *empty list* in list context. That is the result of a bare `return` without a parameter -- it returns `undef` in scalar context and an empty list in list context. But if the elements of the list hadn't been subroutine calls (method calls) but instead simple scalar constants or variables, or if the subroutines had used `return undef` instead of `return` then the trick wouldn't work, so it's a dangerous assumption to make.

Comment: @PatoSáinz:  *"Your typical perl tradeoff"* That's untrue and unnecessarily opinionated. I believe it's poor programming, and at a guess he didn't understand *why* it was working

Comment: @Borodin you're right, I was just generalizing. I've deleted that statement.

Comment: @PatoSáinz: What you wrote was that is is typical of Perl to provide a more concise syntax that won't always work. I'd like you to substantiate that, even as a generalisation

Comment: @Borodin perl regexes, perl one-liners/golf, perl hacks. But it isn't really on topic for me to discuss certain aspects of perl code you can find on the internet.

Comment: @PatoSáinz: Regular expressions *always* work as you have written them, and are part of most popular languages. Similarly, one-liners are as popular, if not more so, in tools like sed and awk. Perl golf is a frivolous pastime, and not to be confused with software programming. And "Perl hacks" seems extremely vague. What about C hacks, Linux hacks, even COBOL hacks? You've said nothing that I think makes Perl typical of brevity at the expense of reliability, and the language can do without more false allegations being levelled at it

Comment: @Borodin I do understand what you say, even tho perl **is** my first choice for a language, an that hackish solutions can happen in almost any environment, we know that sometimes TIMTOWTDI may make horrible things possible. But I know that *bad* programmers, not languages, make *bad* code. I agree with you on all of your points, you should not have taken my "perl tradeoff" comment seriously, it was more tongue-in-cheek.